# Importing records from excel to oracle

Tags: oracle, excel

I have imported records from Excel sheet to Oracle table.  But in the Oracle table column "&" is saved as "amp;". I want it to be saved as "&" only. My column datatype is varchar2.

Answer (score 1):

Do you just want to fix your data?  That's easy enough:

```
SQL> select col1 from t23
  2  /

COL1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ship  amp; shovell
cat in the hat

SQL> update t23
  2  set col1 = replace(col1, 'amp;', chr(38)) 
  3  /

2 rows updated.

SQL> select col1 from t23
  2  /

COL1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ship  & shovell
cat in the hat

SQL>
```

If you want to prevent this happening again you will need to provide us with more details.  Specifically, what process are you using to import the data?  I would guess you're actually using the XML export of the spreadsheet.

Comment: yes i want to prevent it from happening and i am using import from excel method...which we access by right clicking the table in which we want to import records

Comment: @daljeet - "using import from excel method...which we access by right clicking the table"  You must be using some client app or IDE to do this.  You need to say which one if you want more help.